google sheets, conditional formatting based on row numbers
For example: if the rows with row numbers: 3,4 or 5 need to be marked.
These won't work (custom formula):
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROW();{3;4;5})) // marks all rows

=ROW()={3;4;5} // marks one row (#3)


Can you try =ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROW(), {3, 4, 5}, 0)) or =OR(ROW()=3, ROW()=4, ROW()=5) to see if they work? If your locale is EU, it should be =ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROW(); {3; 4; 5}; 0)) and =OR(ROW()=3; ROW()=4; ROW()=5).

As Saddles commented, the match() formula is missing the third parameter. Use this conditional formatting custom formula rule instead:
=match(row(); { 3; 4; 5 }; 0)

See match().
